# Libgdx make Rectangle move

Tags: java, libgdx, iterator, rectangles

I want my llama to change the direction if llama.x < 1100;
But the llama direction will only be changed until the llama.x > -1100, so it stays at -1100/-1099. How can I change it FOREVER(or until I change it again)? Unfortunately a while loop inside the iterator won't work. I tried it hours but I didn't find a solution. I hope you can help me! Here is my code:

```
private void spawnLama() {
    Rectangle livinglama = new Rectangle();
    livinglama.x = -500;
    livinglama.y =  -150;
    livinglama.width = 64;
    livinglama.height = 64;
    LamaXMovement = MathUtils.random(-300, 300);
    livinglamas.put(livinglama, LamaXMovement);
    lastLamaTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}

@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(110 / 255F, 211 / 255F, 43 / 255F, 1 / 255F);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    if(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastLamaTime > 1000000000L) spawnLama();
    Iterator<ObjectMap.Entry<Rectangle, Integer>> iter = livinglamas.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()){
        ObjectMap.Entry<Rectangle, Integer> entry = iter.next();
        Rectangle lama = entry.key;
        int value = entry.value;
if(lama.x <= 1100){
entry.value = -10;
value = -10:
}
            lama.x += value * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        }
        if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            for (Rectangle lama : livinglamas.keys()) {
                if (lama.contains(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY())) {
                    money += 1;
                }
            }
        }
       batch.begin();
        for(Rectangle lama : livinglamas.keys()) {
            batch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, true), lama.x, lama.y);
        }
```

...
EDIT:
I want the Lamas to move naturally. And the speed should not be the same. First I want them to turn at -1100 because this is outside oft the orthographic camera. Then I'll improve it(add more positions where they change directions...)

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want. You want it to move back and forth between -1100 and +1100? Is the `value` you store with each llama a speed? Do you want the speed to be the same when the llama switches direction or should everything move at a speed of 10?

Comment: I want the Lamas to move naturally. And the speed should not be the same. First I want them to turn at -1100 because this is outside oft the orthographic camera. Then I'll improve it(add more positions where they change directions...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest making a `Llama` class to encapsulate the behavior of a llama. This will include the `x` and `y` coordinates and `width` and `height`. You should also have a `speed` or `velocity` value which can be added to the `x` coordinate. Now you can store a list of `Llama` objects rather than the map which you are currently using. Also, when appropriate, you can change the `velocity` from positive to negative or vice versa in order to change direction.

**Addendum:**

First, I would include a `move()` method in the suggested `Llama` class:

```
public class Llama {
  private int x, y, speed;

  void move() {
    x += speed
  }
}
```

Now you can iterate a list using an extended for loop:

```
public class LlamaGame implements ApplicationListener {
  List<Llama> llamas = new ArrayList<>();

  // ...

  @Override
  public void render() {
    // ...
    for (Llama llama : llamas) {
      llama.move()
    }
    // ...
  }
}
```

Finally, the logic to change direction can go inside the `move()` method.

Also, you should look around at some `libgdx` examples. Many of them use separate "renderer" and "controller" classes to separate the logic for these two components of a game.

Comment: Thank You! I tried this but I don't know how to iterate it in render(). Could you give me an example?